# At Liferay to restrict user access using java/javascript

Tags: liferay

What is the code to configure these configurations from the coding site in liferay java? Without going through the settings in admin's panel?
To configure restrictions using code. At MAIN MENU- CONFIGURATION from the admin site. But how to configure each permission for owner, portal content reviewer, portal user and others for add to page, configuration, view and permissions using code either in controller or xml?
For example to restrict view, certain page, or others.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the types of pages and resources you want to restrict, and how you want to restrict them in code (e.g. according to user group, role)?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review [Liferay Development Guide : Security and Permissions](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions)?